# Weaving a binary file from an object file using LD and objcopy

Tags: c, gcc, ld, elf, objcopy

I am trying to build a custom binary file which data mostly comes from a .o file, compiled from a big C file which looks like the following:

```
int a[] = { ... };
int b[] = { ... };
int c[] = { ... };
```

This C file basically contains a big set of data arrays, all declared within the same section. An important note here is that I cannot modify the content of this C file.

Is it possible, using LD scripts, objcopy, or any other tool, to weave a set of output binary files containg just one or a few of these variables, in a specific order (not necessarily the same order as they appear in the C file)?

I tried to use a LD script for this, but the finest granularity of inclusion seems to be the section of an object file. To achieve what I want I would need to be able to reference symbols directly.

The output will ultimately be a simple binary file (generated using *objcopy -Obinary*), containing only the concatenation of the desired arrays. So for this question we can assume that I only need to output all data in a single section (i.e. there is no code, nor is there any other input than this big C file).

Comment: Where else does the binary file take input from? Please be more specific about the structure of the desired output.

Comment: Added a paragraph with the details you asked - sorry for having been unclear.